# REDIS PUBSUB in Cluster Mode(AWS ElastiCache) giving duplicate message to subscribers

Tags: go, redis

I am using  github.com/redis/go-redis/v9 v9.3.1
to do redis ops in a chat application.

One requirement of this chat app is to show user typing messages on screen and show the status to other connected clients just like we have in similar chatting apps.

Other use case is to deliver actual msgs.We are achieving this using redis pubsub. That is a dedicated subscriber go-routine is spinned up on a given channel on every machine and every message delivered on that channel is sent to all subscribers(who might be connected on different machines of chat-server using web-socket).So far so good.
I cannot help but notice that I get a lot of dups arriving to end users/testers.

I was reading a bit about way redis  internally works and it seems that in cluster Mode message in pub-sub is delivered /replicated to all the slave nodes in cluster and that might lead to dups because client is connected to all nodes in cluster.

```
var redisClient = redis.NewClusterClient(&redis.ClusterOptions{
    Addrs: []string{"c1:6379",
        "c2:6379",
        "c3:6379"},

    ReadOnly:       false,
    RouteRandomly:  false,
    RouteByLatency: false,
    PoolSize:       10,
    MinIdleConns:   10,

    DialTimeout:  5 * time.Second,
    ReadTimeout:  3 * time.Second,
    WriteTimeout: 3 * time.Second,
    PoolTimeout:  4 * time.Second,

    //IdleCheckFrequency: 60 * time.Second,
    //IdleTimeout:        5 * time.Minute,
    //MaxConnAge:         0 * time.Second,

    MaxRetries:      10,
    MinRetryBackoff: 8 * time.Millisecond,
    MaxRetryBackoff: 512 * time.Millisecond,

    TLSConfig: &tls.Config{
        InsecureSkipVerify: true,
    },
})




func InitializeStatusMessageSubscriber(statusTopic string, cm *ConnectionManager) {
    subscriber := redisClient.Subscribe(ctx, statusTopic)
    log.Printf("Subscribing to status subscriber in go-routine %s", statusTopic)
    var socketEventTypingStatus SocketEventTypingMessage

    channel := subscriber.Channel()

    for msg := range channel {
        if marshalError := json.Unmarshal([]byte(msg.Payload), &socketEventTypingStatus); marshalError != nil {
            log.Println("Error unmarshalling message to SocketEventTypingStatus message", marshalError)
            return
        }
        messageId := socketEventTypingStatus.Id
        expired := CheckIfKeyIsExpired(messageId)
        if expired {
            continue
        }

        id := socketEventTypingStatus.ChatId

        users := GetAllUsersForAGivenChat(id)

        for _, user := range users {
            cm.WriteMessageToUserSocket(user, msg.Payload)
        }
    }
}
```

InitializeStatusMessageSubscriber is initialised only once.